# Good book to make transition to theoretical statistics?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, references

I am about to finish my undergrad degree in statistics and data science. I am about to start a Masters in Statistics. I took Mathematical Statistics I where we used Mathematical Statistics with Application by Wackerly, Mendenhall and Scheaffer, and we covered the first 6 chapters in the course, the book and the one semester course were clear and understandable. For the second part of the course, Math Stats II, since I will start a Masters in Statistics I was allowed to take the graduate version of the course. I am falling behind and the book we are using is 'Theoretical Statistics: Topics for a Core Course, by Keener', I find the book really difficult to read and I am not understanding the material. I am worried and would like to know if anyone has any book recommendation to transition reading more dense and theoretical material in statistics. I really don't want to have weak foundations in this core topics about the subject.

Comment: Could you include some of your other courses and background? Particularly in math?

Comment: How about the second half of Wackerley? And of course Casella & Berger is the canonical intro to advanced math stats book.